# Rust: Why the first borrow later used here?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am learning rust and was trying to implement a singly linked list. Everything went well until I tried to implement a function that removes the tail from the list.

The definition of the LinkedList:

```
pub struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    ele: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;
```

I first tried to use `while let` but failed:

```
impl<T: Copy + std::fmt::Debug> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn pop_tail_not_working_1(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut cur = &mut self.head;
        while let Some(node) = cur {
            if node.next.is_none() {
                return cur.take().map(|tail| tail.ele);
            }
            cur = &mut node.next;
        }
        None
    }
}
```

with the error message

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*cur` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/linked_list.rs:66:24
   |
64 |         while let Some(node) = cur {
   |                        ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
65 |             if node.next.is_none() {
66 |                 return cur.take().map(|tail| tail.ele);
   |                        ^^^
   |                        |
   |                        second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                        first borrow later used here
```

Then I tried the `loop + match`, still failed:

```
impl<T: Copy + std::fmt::Debug> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn pop_tail_not_working_2(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut cur = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match cur {
                None => return None,
                Some(node) => {
                    if node.next.is_none() {
                        return cur.take().map(|tail| tail.ele);
                    }
                    cur = &mut node.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with similar error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*cur` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/linked_list.rs:54:32
   |
52 |                 Some(node) => {
   |                      ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
53 |                     if node.next.is_none() {
54 |                         return cur.take().map(|tail| tail.ele);
   |                                ^^^
   |                                |
   |                                second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                first borrow later used here
```

Finally, I tried the `match` guard, and it worked

```
impl<T: Copy + std::fmt::Debug> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn pop_tail(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut cur = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match cur {
                None => return None,
                Some(node) if node.next.is_none() => {
                    return cur.take().map(|tail| tail.ele);
                }
                Some(node) => cur = &mut node.next,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the third implementation works but the first two don't, I think they all share the same logic. Specifically, I am really confused with the phrase `first borrow later used here`, I can't tell why the first borrow is used when the second mutable borrowed happen?

Comment: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: @Stargateur I don't think the `too-many-list` implements a similar function that removes the tail or an arbitrary link from the list.

Comment: The point of that link is that linked lists are notoriously hard to get right in Rust, due to complexities with the borrow checker that aren't present in garbage-collected languages.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes, I agree. But I tried to learn rust the hard way. Also, the third implementation works, and I try to understand the error message of the first two implementations.

Comment: Through your edits you've completely changed what is being asked. You should have opened another question instead.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I have asked the moderator to delete it. But I don't think it has been completely changed since I have described the details in the question from the beginning. I was not looking for a solution, I have already posted a workable implementation in the question body and looking for an explanation.

Comment: I've often felt there should be a good reference explaining these types of errors with plenty of real case examples. I can easily see why the last two implementations would be confusing. The only seeming difference, syntactically, is the guard expression on one of the match arms. Maybe just explaining that one thing in a straightforward way would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could track the size of your linked list so you know how to modify it depending on the size:

```rust
pub struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
    size: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    ele: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

impl<T> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            head: None,
            size: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn pop_tail(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.size == 0 {
            return None;
        }
        if self.size == 1 {
            let res = self.head.take().map(|n| n.ele);
            self.size -= 1;
            return res;
        }
        let mut last_node = self.head.as_mut();
        for _ in 0..self.size-2 {
            last_node = last_node.and_then(|e| e.next.as_mut());
        }
        self.size -= 1;
        last_node.unwrap().next.take().map(|n| n.ele)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = LinkedList {
        head: Some(Box::new(Node {ele: 10, next: Some(Box::new(Node {ele: 20, next: None}))})),
        size: 2,
    };
    
    
    let value = list.pop_tail();
    println!("{}", list.size);
    println!("{}", value.unwrap());
    
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0590d34bff2fd827ba950dfc3ef665e)

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to work with "owned" values rather than with references.

Implementation:

```
impl<T> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn pop_tail(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.head.is_none() {
            return None;
        }

        let mut node = self.head.take().unwrap();
        let mut tail = &mut self.head;

        while let Some(next) = node.next.take() {
            *tail = Some(node);
            tail = &mut tail.as_mut().unwrap().next;
            node = next;
        }

        Some(node.ele)
    }
}
```

A rather lame test-case ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7a755b946d5f1442b98df43d98ddbff)):

```
fn main() {
    let mut head: LinkedList<i32> = LinkedList { head: None };
    println!("Before: {:?}", head);
    assert_eq!(None, head.pop_tail());
    println!("After: {:?}", head);

    let mut head = LinkedList {
        head: Some(Box::new(Node { next: None, ele: 1 })),
    };
    println!("Before: {:?}", head);
    assert_eq!(Some(1), head.pop_tail());
    println!("After: {:?}", head);

    let mut head = LinkedList {
        head: Some(Box::new(Node {
            ele: 1,
            next: Some(Box::new(Node { next: None, ele: 2 })),
        })),
    };
    println!("Before: {:?}", head);
    assert_eq!(Some(2), head.pop_tail());
    println!("After: {:?}", head);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree "the owned value" can make things much simpler. But I don't want to consume the original data structure.

Comment: From the PoV of any outside observer, the datastructure is not "consumed" in any way. Due to rust's "zero-cost" abstractions, copying the `Option<Box<T>>` is as expensive as copying the reference to `Option<Box<T>>` but without the wrestling with the borrowchecker.

Comment: Yes, the implementation bypasses the borrow checker. But can we do it more in a more idiomatic way?

Comment: I believe using `.take()` as you have it in an example is going to eat up the list. `.take()` passes ownership to the caller and replaces the original option with `None`.

Comment: @Todd if run the playground example, you'll see that it does not eat up the list

Comment: Oh, I see. Because of this line: *tail = Some(node);, which puts it back.